# How do I use windows 10's lock-screen background for desktop

Tags: windows-10, desktop-customization

I've noticed that my windows 10 laptop has a really nice, automatic updating lock screen background, is there a way to use the same background for my desktop?

The background image is stored somewhere on disk, but I have no idea how to find it.

Answer (score 2):

These lockscreen images are called Spotlight images and yes, they're pretty.

You can find them by navigating to this folder in your computer:

```
%localappdata%\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets
```

Unfortunately, they are not saved as picture files you would recognize, but...

If you **copy** these files out to a new folder (Important: Do NOT cut them!) you can rename then in bulk by using the command prompt and a command like...

```
ren <path to copied files>\*.* <path to copied files>\*.jpg
```

...and you'll get a nice folder-full of all the pretty lockscreen images from Spotlight.

*Note: be careful running that command. It has the capability of causing lots of trouble if you aren't careful to run it ONLY in the folder you copied those images to.*

Answer (score 1):

There is a command line application called [Lock Screen Reflection](http://vdsfreak.com/post/156133535205/lsr) that will grab the current lock screen at the time of execution and sets it to your desktop. Unfortunately it is not open sourced.

You execute it from the command line as follows:

```
lsr.exe 3
```

The number indicates style:

```
0 for Tiled
1 for Centered
2 for Stretched
3 for Fit
4 for Fill
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small utility called **Lock2Desktop** that accomplishes this:

[image: Lock2Desktop Screenshot]

Learn more at: https://beautifullifeapps.com/pages/Lock2Desktop